# Calling on existing classes?

Tags: c#, class, monogame

I'm quite stomped... I can't seem to find a straight answer for "How to call a method, or get a variable from another class". What I want to do is to let a second script to use a variable on the main script (Game1.cs), or to trigger a method.

The only way I know of doing this is to make a new instance of it

```
Game1 mainScript = new Game1();
```

Then call on it like this`mainScript.myVariable`But I know this won't work, because I created a new Game1, not using the original. I'm wondering if there is a way to call on the  already existing class, then use its variables.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's going to depend on the specifics of the situation; it's going to depend on what the relationship is between these two classes are, what their purposes are, etc.

Comment: Describe in detail exactly what classes you have in mind and what can not access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
namespace TestOfFunctions;
{
    public class Game1
    {
        private static int _someVariable = 15;
        public static int SomeVariable
        {
            get { return _someVariable; }
            set { _someVariable = value; }
        }
    }
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine (Game1.SomeVariable);
            Game1.SomeVariable = 30;
            Console.WriteLine (Game1.SomeVariable);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's quite easy. You need just make sure that you has included related namespace (testOfFunctions for this example) to use your class. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks!, can't believe I didn't realize to use static :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you will use `static` class.
This type of class avoid to create a new instance (a static class cannot be instantiated)

Visit for more reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/79b3xss3.aspx